# Using bootstrap to create this layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm able to somewhat approximate it using columns, but the rows don't align and they collapse in a diagonal fashion. So I thought I'd just start over and ask for any help on making a responsive version of this. When the screen shrinks, each unit should stack on top of each other.

Here's what I'm trying to create:

[image: mockup]

And here's my starting point.

HTML:

```
<div class="unit">
  <div id="blue" class="square"></div>
  <div class="text">Blue text Lorem Ipsum Blue text Lorem Ipsum Blue text       Lorem Ipsum Blue text Lorem Ipsum Blue text Lorem Ipsum Blue text Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>

<div class="unit">
  <div id="red" class="square"></div>
  <div class="text">
  Red Text Lorem Ipsum Red Text Lorem Ipsum Red Text Lorem Ipsum Red Text     Lorem Ipsum Red Text Lorem Ipsum Red Text Lorem Ipsum
  </div>
</div>

<div class="unit">
  <div id="yellow" class="square"></div>
  <div class="text">
Yellow Text Lorem Ipsum Yellow Text Lorem Ipsum Yellow Text Lorem Ipsum     Yellow Text Lorem Ipsum Yellow Text Lorem Ipsum Yellow Text Lorem Ipsum </div>
</div>

<div class="unit">
  <div id="green" class="square"></div>
  <div class="text">Green Text Lorem Ipsum Green Text Lorem Ipsum Green Text     Lorem Ipsum Green Text Lorem Ipsum Green Text Lorem Ipsum Green Text Lorem Ipsum     Green Text Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

CSS (no layout)

```
.square{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#blue{
  background-color: blue;
}

#red{
  background-color: red;
}

#yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Is it okay to do this in a table with html. This is a good way to get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: HTML tables for layout are not a good idea. It was tried in the 90's - avoid doing this if possible as there are many (better) ways of achieving this nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap you would rely on the Grid system.  In the below example I have used `.container-fluid` and `.col-xs-6` to create a grid with a two-column format regardless of screen size.

```css
.unit {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.square {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 15px 5px 0;
 }

.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.yellow {
  background: #ffff00;
}

.green {
  background: #00ff00;
}

.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
 
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="unit">
    <div class="square blue"></div>
    <div class="text">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="unit">
    <div class="square red"></div>
    <div class="text">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="unit">
    <div class="square yellow"></div>
    <div class="text">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-6">
   <div class="unit">
    <div class="square green"></div>
    <div class="text">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>    
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But here the units don't convert to 4 vertical units, is this not easily done in bootstrap? Additionally, the text is wrapping (in the image it does not wrap), and text-overflow: hidden isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

use the bootstrap gridsystem

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="unit col-md-6">
      <div id="blue" class="square col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="text col-md-6">Blue text Lorem Ipsum Blue text Lorem Ipsum Blue text       Lorem Ipsum Blue text Lorem Ipsum Blue text Lorem Ipsum Blue text Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="unit col-md-6">
      <div id="red" class="square col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="text col-md-6">
      Red Text Lorem Ipsum Red Text Lorem Ipsum Red Text Lorem Ipsum Red Text     Lorem Ipsum Red Text Lorem Ipsum Red Text Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

and repeat the row for the others rows
  ......